# How to add +1 value on the entire column of my database table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

Just new in programming I created a database using **XAMPP** with 3 columns (`f_name, l_name, age`).

I created a `index.php` page where I have only 1 button present, what I am expecting to happen is that if I click that button the entire column `age` will commit +1 to all current values inside the `age`. Is it possible?

But unfortunately I don't know how to create the code. I would like to see a simple example of code that will add +1 to the entire column of `age`. At lease a base logic that will help me figure it out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to increment the ages of everyone in the table:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `table` SET `age` = `age` + 1");
```

If you want to update a specific person:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `table` SET `age` = `age` + 1 WHERE f_name='firstname' AND l_name='lastname'");
```

(replace 'firstname' & 'lastname' of the person you want to update)

You should add a primary key field (an auto incrementing integer) to your table, it makes updating individual rows much simpler (and much quicker for the database engine to perform):

```
mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `table` SET `age` = `age` + 1 WHERE id=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `table` SET `age` = `age` + 1");
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*`, anymore, they are depecrated

Comment: little bit a habit i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to add +1 to the entire column of `age`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs99o.png)
Query:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/527Xq.png)
Ajax:

Thank you everyone.